# Finding "Largest Possible Approximation" of rate of change from a table?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In this Calculus question, they give me a table:

x = 0.9 , 1.0 , 1.2

f(x) = 1.226 , 1 , 0.754

I have to find the "largest possible approximation" of the rate of change of $f$ at $x=1$.

I actually have no idea what this is or how to find it... but I think it has something to do with the derivative.